# How to truncate auto-generated entry titles?

Tags: titles, auto-generate

I am auto-generating entry titles based on a plain text field. Now, I would like to limit the characters the title contains of (e.g. 50 chars while the plain text field has 500 chars). How could I do that?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use any Twig in the dynamic title field. There are plugins that provide Twig filters to truncate text, but here’s how you can do simple truncation without any plugin.

```
{{ object.myTextField|length > 50 ? object.myTextField|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' : object.myTextField }}
```